# Condition for a chord of contact to subtend a right angle at the center.

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

This is a question from SL Loney's The Elements of Coordinate Geometry

> Find the condition that the chord of contact of tangents from the point $$ (x' , y') $$ to the circle $$ x^2 + y^2 = a^2 $$ will subtend a right angle at the center.

My plan is first we should find the equation of chord of contact, which by definition is $$ xx' + yy' = a^2 $$ and then find the endpoints of this chord by solving the system of equations $$ xx' + yy' = a^2$$ $$x^2 + y^2 = a^2$$. Once we get the endpoints then the chord must satisfy the Pythagorean theorem in order to subtend a right angle [image]

That is to say it must follow this condition $$ a^2 + a^2 = AB^2 $$.
But the problem is by this approach I'm led into very messy algebra which seems unsolvable and hence I got stuck. I want to know is there any problem in my principles which I have mentioned above?

I looked up it's solution on internet and I found this [image]

Things become confusing when the author says " *we* *make (1) homogenous with the help of (2)"* My doubts are :-

1. What is homogenous after all?
2. Why do we need to that? Can't we solve it by geometrical rules which I have outlined above?
3. Did he do that (that homogenous) only to solve this particular problem or is it something conventional which I'm ignorant of?

Thank you. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$1)$ I bealive that making the equation $1$ homogeneous is substituting in itself the second equation, obtaining a polynomial equal to $0$.

$2)$You need that to solve, algebrically, the problem. You can solve this problem in a geometrical way: in fact so that angles $\measuredangle OAP= \measuredangle OBP=90$ then $OAPB$ has to be a square. From here the point $P$ stays on a circunference $\gamma$ of radius $OP=\sqrt{2}\cdot OB=\sqrt a \cdot OB$. The equation of $\gamma$ is so: $x^2+y^2=2a^2$.

$3)$ Making an equation homogeneous can be sometimes a really helpful tecnique to solve algebrically or geometrically a problem.

Comment: I'm still not understanding what homogenous equation is and how to make it? On google it's just showing about homogenous differential equations.

Comment: It means easily that all of the monomial that compose the equation have the same degree.